# Why do I have a "Linux" part in Windows 10 File Explorer?

Tags: linux, windows-10, windows-explorer

I just noticed a "Linux" part in Windows 10 File Explorer.
I say part because I'm not even sure how to call this, it's not a drive... it's at the same level as OneDrive, This PC, Network... then Linux (the logo is the Linux penguin). I does not contain anything visible (no windows hidden files). Properties for this item say "The properties for this item are not available."

Should I worry about this?

I have not installed any kind of dual boot, and I don't see any unknown partition in disk management (or maybe ... there's a recovery partition that have no actions possible to it, only "Help", which I don't remember if it was created by Windows).

---

Edit: Now I remember that a few month ago, for a short-live .NET project, I was required to install something named WSL2... Because it was a requirement for Docker or something... I was in hurry and simply followed instructions.
I think that I have uninstalled WSL2 since then though... I would be still be interested in how to remove this Linux things.

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/04/access-wsl-files-windows-explorer

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I don't has a NAS, I have other computers but all active computer are on Windows 10/11. I have a few old laptops where I installed Linux but I nearly never use them.

Comment: It is indeed likely to be WSL. From https://www.fourco.nl/blogs/access-to-wsl-filesystem-in-explorer/ "Alternatively, in Windows 11, Microsoft also added a nice Linux list item and icon to the navigation pane. Selecting that also shows your available WSL filesystems." As you found the potential solution you can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Please provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The following information was originally edited into the question itself, but is actually the OP's own self-answer.  Moving this out of the question and into an answer:*

> After searching some different info, I stumbled upon a screenshot of something setting window named "Turn Windows features on and off", I checked it again though I had already checked it... And found that "Windows Subsystem for Linux" was checked (different "checked", the checkbox was checked) ... thought I had already checked the other day an missed it. I uncheked the checkbox... I will know on next restart if this removed the penguin (can't restart right now).

*The OP is welcome to create a self-answer and mark it accepted.  They can then request deletion of this copy by flagging it for a Mod (custom reason).  Or, if they prefer, they can simply accept this, or another, answer.*

Comment: I did not write it has an answer but as addition information in the question because it is not an answer to the question. This info seemed relevant since people were suggestion editing registry while there exists a settings in Windows. But the main question was "Why do I have this Linux thing". This is the answer to a subquestion that came along that was "how to remove it?"? And this should not have been removed from where it was, sorry.

Comment: @TTT Hmm - But it is also the *answer* to the original question of what was causing it (WSL).  Or maybe we needed to move the original edit over as well?

Comment: In that sense, you may be right. One thing is, back then, I installed something called WSL2  in a hurry and I had not got that it may be the letters for "Windows Subsystem Linux"...
Maybe I would need to clarify this questions. But I don't have time right now...
But, yeah, OK. I guess if people read these comments as well it'll make enough sense..

Answer (score 1):

Under this Linux branch you will find, if you open it up,
your installed WSL distributions.

If WSL was not fully installed or removed, and if no distributions
are currently installed, but still "Linux" is shown,
to remove it from the Navigation Pane of the current user
do this:

Create a `.reg` file with the following contents and double-click
it to execute:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{B2B4A4D1-2754-4140-A2EB-9A76D9D7CDC6}]
@="Linux"
"System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree"=dword:00000000
```

Reference :
[How to Add or Remove Linux in Navigation Pane of File Explorer in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/127506-add-remove-linux-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Did you uninstall the distribution using `wsl --unregister distroName`? What exactly did you uninstall?

Comment: I don't think I installed any Linux distribution, I only followed steps to make the container platform run on Windows. I think it was Docker and WSL2 for Windows something like this. (Maybe I have traces in some archives, but can't access them right now.)

Answer (score -1):

It's actually related to the WSL, which allows you to run Linux distros on Windows 10. It's a pretty cool feature that's been around since the Creators Update back in 2017. As for why it's there and what it's for, think of it as a virtualized environment for Linux, meaning you can run Linux apps and access its file system right from within Windows. You won't see any files or folders in the "Linux" section because it's just a shortcut to access the WSL distro you have installed. If you need more info on how to use WSL or want to learn about the different distros available, you can check out this site [tuxcare.com](https://tuxcare.com/extended-lifecycle-support/centos-7-extended-support/). They've got all the goods on how to get the most out of WSL.

Comment: This is incorrect. It's not a shortcut to launch WSL. This item lets you browse files inside installed WSL distros. If there are none, it's empty.